# Numpy strange behavior past end of array

Tags: python, numpy, indexing, slice

Normally, if you attempt to assign past the end of an array in numpy, the non-existent elements are disregarded.

```
>>> x = np.zeros(5)
>>> x[3:6] = np.arange(5)[2:5]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (3) into shape (2)
```

However, the same operation entirely past the end of the array "succeeds" if only one element is assigned:

```
>>> x[5:] = np.arange(5)[4:]
>>> x[5:] = np.arange(5)[4:100]
```

This only works if the RHS has one element:

```
>>> x[5:] = np.arange(5)[3:]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (2) into shape (0)
```

Why is this the case? How is it possible not to get an error here? Is this behavior documented, or is it a bug?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In keeping with Python list behavior, you can slice off-the-end.  The first case shows that's true for both the LHS and RHS.

The rest is broadcasting.  3 can't got into 2.  2 can't go into 0.  But 1 can go into anything, including 0. We tend to think of broadcasting replicating a size 1 dimension to something larger, but replicating to 0 also works.

Comment: This certainly explains everything. I would argue that it's very much against the whole idea of returning expected results, but that's an entirely different matter.